# floatflt - removing extra white space on top

Tags: spacing, floats, wrap

When I include a figure via `floatfigure` into my text, I can't get it to stick to the top margin of the text body. There is always some white space left. I even tried to look in the package code, but didn't find any clues to where it comes from. How can I chop it off?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,russian,open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=14.8cm, paperheight=21.0cm, top=1.1cm, bottom=1.8cm, twoside, inner=0.9cm, outer=1.8cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm, footskip=1cm, headsep=0cm, headheight=0cm, voffset=0cm, hoffset=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, marginparwidth=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[leadingfraction=1.0]{savetrees}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.95} 

\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} 
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.25em} 

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=15\baselineskip, width=0.4\linewidth]{dummy}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{floatingfigure}

--- Нет-нет! Одну! И левретку! Или болонку. Или мопса... Или вообще...

--- Мопса!!!~--- Серафима умудрилась вложить в название этой породы всю силу своего негодования и презрения.~--- Мопса!!!.. Черепашку ещё предложи!!! На верёвочке!!!

Царевич поёжился, ибо именно черепашка и не успела сорваться с его языка. 

--- А п-почему~--- <<на верёвочке>>?

--- Чтоб не убежала!!!.. Послушай, Иванушка. Почему мы не можем съездить в гости к Ярославне? Или в Вондерланд? Или просто на недельку поохотиться в лес?

--- Но десять дней назад мы же выезжали на охоту!~--- ухватился Иван за безопасную тему.

--- Выезжали!~--- снова упёрла руки в бока и стала похожа на маленькую, разгневанную букву <<Ф>> Серафима.~--- Если не принимать во внимание, что охотились \emph{вы}, а мне с \emph{боярышнями\/} пришлось всё это время просидеть в шатре на платочках, чтобы не обгореть на палящем сентябрьском солнце и не запачкать платье об траву, то конечно, выезжали!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Because I will always have to wrap multiple paragraphs around my figure, this package provided the only working solution.
If there are another approaches - I'll be glad to test them.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues in finding this spacing.  The `floatflt` package places the figure on  the current line but raised by `0.3\baselineskip`.  So initially all you need to do is add a `\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}` at the beginning of the float to raise it one full baselineskip.  However, at the top of the that is too much, as the base of the first line is essentially `\topskip` from the top of the text area, so we need to push the box down by `0.3\baselineskip` and up by `\topskip`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\setlength{\figgutter}{0pt}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage{lipsum} %For dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{0.4\linewidth}%
  \vspace{\dimexpr0.3\baselineskip-\topskip}%
  \noindent
  \includegraphics[height=15\baselineskip,width=0.4\linewidth]{dummy}%
\end{floatingfigure}

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I have stripped out irrelevant packages from your code.  Also the `\intextsep` and `\textfloatsep` play no role in `floatflt`.  On the other hand there is `\floatgutter` which specifies the horizontal space between the float and the text.  In your case, there was a paragraph indent before you figure, I cancelled this with `\noindent`.

Comment: It should have been obvious, but `\vspace` saved me looking around for something more complicated.